# Unable to access models and helper classes in custom class file laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have created a common class in app/Classes/Common.php
but whenever i try to access a model in a class function.

```
$new_booking_request = BookingRequest::where('host_id','=',Auth::id())
```

I am getting this error

```
Class 'App\Models\BookingRequest' not found
```

Even other classes like Auth, URL and Cookie are not working.
Is there a way to bring all classes in my Common class scope?

Comment: `use Session, Cookie;` (after namespace) or `\Session::get()` etc.

Answer (score 1):

You get this issue when your namespace is wrong you or you forgot to namespace.

Since common.php is inside App/Classes, inside Common.php do somethng like this:

```
<?php namespace App\Classes;

use View, Auth, URL; 

class Common {
    //class methods
}
```

Also ensure your model class has the correct namespace, if BookingRequest.php is located inside App\Models then inside BookingRequest.php do this:

```
<?php namespace App\Models;

    BookingRequest extends \Eloquent {
        //other definitions
    }
```

Then if you wish to use BookingRequest.php outside its namespace or in another namespace like so:

```
<?php namespace App\Classes;

use App\Models\BookingRequest;

use View, Auth, URL; 

    class Common {
        //class methods
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 5 everything is namespaced, make sure your class has a proper namespace and that you are calling it using that same namespace you specified.

To include classes in another class make sure that you use the `use` keyword to import the necessary classes on top of your class definition. Also you can call the class globally with the `\`. Ex: `\Auth`, `\URL` and `\Cookie`

For the namespace in L5 here is a quick example:

```
<?php namespace App\Models;

class BookingRequest {
  // class definition  
}
```

then when trying to call that class, either call the full namespace path of the function, or include the function.

```
<?php

class HomeController extends Controller {

  public function index()
  {
    $newBookingRequest = App\Models\BookingRequest::where('host_id','=',Auth::id());
  }

}
```

OR

```
<?php namespace App\Controllers;

use App\Models\BookingRequest; // Include the class

class HomeController extends Controller {

  public function index()
  {
    $newBookingRequest = BookingRequest::where('host_id','=',Auth::id());
  }

}
```

PS:

Please use `camelCase` when defining class attributes and methods as this helps for a better code-styling and naming conventions when using the L5 framework.